# Extremely large latency in Google App Engine Web App

Tags: google-app-engine

I have signed up for the Google Cloud Free trial and tried out the App Engine with my Java Spring Boot web app.

I've managed to deploy my Spring Boot Application onto the app engine using this guide:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-app-engine-springboot/#0

However my web app seems to be running extremely slow. I am getting very high latency on loading small static files. Like 2-3 seconds for each 2KB .js file that the web app is serving.

I've tested the app on Amazons AWS Elastic Beanstalk platform, and the app is running smooth and as expected there.

I know that I haven't provided much info, but I'm not sure what to include here. It seems like it's just working really slow "right out of the box".

Any ideas why this may be, or what I can do to fix/test this?

Comment: ifs its static files, try using google firebase instead.

Comment: In order to assist you, we need more information like in what region was the app deployed and where are these static files located.

Comment: Region: europe-west. The files are contained inside the Jar file and are served with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf.

Comment: A useful tool for this kind of situations is Stackdriver Trace. If you go to the Navigation Menu → Logging → Logs and filter by GAE Application, module and version, you can view the request logs. In there you have the latency of each request. You can click on one and click on “View trace”. From the trace page you can isolate the calls and view in detail of there’s any call taking more time than usual. Could you verify this and share with us if you find any call taking a long time?